# Complex MySQL Join with 3 tables and many2many relations

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables person, account and subscription. Account belongs to Person as one to many and Account and Subscription are many to many.I need a sql which can select data from three tables.-

Person Tables

```
+----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| username                   | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| password                   | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| account_id                 | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------------------+---------------+------+---------------+----------------+
```

### Account table

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |

+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| yearly_renew | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date_joined  | date         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_renewed | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| signup       | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| reason       | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| yearly_total | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| total        | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Account-Subscription table

```
+-----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| account_id      | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| subscription_id | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Subscription table

```
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| subscription_type | varchar(150) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| hold              | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| start_date        | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| end_date          | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| amount_paid       | double       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| date_paid         | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| transaction_id    | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| free              | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Expecting output in a single query -

OUTPUT

```
+-----------+------------+--------------+
| person.id | account.id | subscription.id |
+-----------+------------+--------------+
|     10    |      11 |           20 |
|     15    |      32 |           45 |
|     23    |      43 |         null |
+--------+---------+-----------------+
```

Comment: There is nothing in these tables that links a person to an account

Comment: Instead of these, Provide information about Data in table..

Comment: @DaleM update the person table.

Answer (score 2):

**try this. it may works properly...**

```
SELECT  p.Id AS person.id
       ,p.account_id AS account.id
       ,acsub.subscription_id as subscription.id
FROM   Person AS p
       LEFT JOIN Account-Subscription AS acsub ON p.account_id=acsub.account_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  p.Id AS person.id
       ,p.account_id AS account.id
       ,acsub.subscription_id as subscription.id
FROM   Person AS p
       INNER JOIN
       Account-Subscription AS acsub ON p.account_id=acsub.account_id
```

Comment: Thnx @daleM, you query works, but I didn't clear the exact output. the count of person table is 36014 but your query return me -  24832. I want all data that belong person, if the subscription is not available the subscription will be null. Make sense ?

Comment: Update the expected output.